# Making html form keep posted elements after submit

Tags: php, html

I am trying to have my form keep and display the posted texts in the form after submit. I have this so far and it empties after submit. Any suggestions?

```
<td  style="t" bgcolor="#FFCC00" width="21"><sub> <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" name="A1" id="A1" value="<?php if 
    (isset($A1)){echo $A1; }?>"></sub></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$A1` will be unset, as PHP won't register POST parameters for you automatically (as long as you have register_globals turned off in php.ini). Thus, you need to dig a bit deeper to have access to the posted data, it is available within the $_POST superglobal associative array.

```
<td style="t" bgcolor="#FFCC00" width="21">
    <sub>
        <input type="text" size="1" maxlength="1" name="A1" id="A1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['A1']) ? $_POST['A1'] : null; ?>">
    </sub>
</td>
```

Comment: Awesome,it works. Can you explain your answer a little further.

Comment: Added a bit more detailed explanation.